Update array specific items

I want only items in  list entityParameters will update in  x.Params
by Id , update all items of entityParameters if entityParameters.Id == x.Params.Id

List<Param> entityParameters

filter = Builders<MachineObj>.Filter.Where(x => x.MachineId == id);

update = Builders<MachineObj>.Update
            .Set(x => x.Params, entityParameters);


I don't know MongoDb but what about somthing like:
Builders.ToList().Where(x => x.MachineId == id).ForEach(x => x.Param = entityParameters);
and then [=> db.SaveChanges()]

        List<ArrayFilterDefinition> arrayFilters = new();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in entityParameters)
        {
            var updateItem = Builders<MachineObj>.Update.Set($"Params.$[elem{i}]", item);

            arrayFilters.Add(new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(
               new BsonDocument($"elem{i}.ParamId", item.ParamId)
            ));

            update = Builders<MachineObj>.Update.Combine(update, updateItem);

            i++;
        }

        updateOptions = new UpdateOptions
        {
            ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
        };

    await machinesDB.Machines.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, updateOptions);


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here is an approach to update only the items in x.Params that match the Id of items in entityParameters, using the MongoDB C# driver. This involves iterating over entityParameters and creating update definitions for each item:
List<Param> entityParameters = ...;

var filter = Builders<MachineObj>.Filter.Eq(x => x.MachineId, id);

var updateBuilder = Builders<MachineObj>.Update;

UpdateDefinition<MachineObj> combinedUpdate = updateBuilder.Combine();

foreach (var param in entityParameters)
{
    var arrayFilter = Builders<MachineObj>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Params, p => p.Id == param.Id);

    var update = updateBuilder.Set(x => x.Params[-1], param);

    combinedUpdate = updateBuilder.Combine(combinedUpdate, update);
}

var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, combinedUpdate);


you didnt use arrayFilter
